# pg_basebackup PostgreSQL statement fails

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, database-backups

I am trying to execute `pg_basebackup` command to take base backup but I do not see a success statement when I execute the command. Is there anything else where I went wrong?

```
pg_basebackup -h127.0.0.1 -U owner -D backup -Ft -z -P
```

Comment: Can you please bring the error message ?

Comment: Are you trying to run the command on a regular command prompt, or are you trying to run it using a connection to the PostgreSQL server with (e.g.) `psql`?

Comment: I am trying to run the command on SQL shell (psql)

Comment: Syntax error at or near "pg_basebackup"

Comment: pg_basebackup is a program, not an SQL command.  You run it from the system shell, not from inside psql.